# Prove that a continuous function on a closed interval attains a maximum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, alternative-proof

As the title indicates, I'd like to prove the following:

> If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$, then $f$ attains its maximum.

Now, I do have a working proof: $[a,b]$ is a connected, compact space, which means that because $f$ is continuous, $f([a,b])$ is compact and connected as well.  Therefore, $f([a,b])$ is a closed interval, which means it has both a minimum and, as desired, a maximum.

What I would like, however, is a proof that doesn't require such general or sophisticated framework.  In particular, I'd like to know if there's a proof that is understandable to somebody beginning calculus, one that (at the very least) doesn't invoke compactness.  Any comments, hints, or solutions are welcome and apreciated.

Comment: It seems that I've made the mistake of not checking wikipedia first.  This page has a nice proof along the same lines of some of these answerers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Proving_the_theorems

Comment: Note, this problem is badly formed - you define the domain of $f$ as $\mathbb R$ and then ask about a maximum. What you want is the maximum on $[a,b]$

Comment: Is their anything around for if a function is continuous on [a,b] attains a min value on [a,b]. I know how to prove it using sequences and compact sets. I need a third way to go about it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @EduardoO. are you asking specifically about attaining the *minimum* as opposed to the maximum?  Then of course, all the same arguments work.  If you'd prefer not to slightly rephrase one of the arguments below, it suffices to show that the function $g(x) = -f(x)$ attains a maximum, then use one of the arguments directly.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom To be honest some of the arguments below get me lost as some of things I have yet to learn or are completely new to me. I need a proof that I can interpret to show the $minimum$, yes opposed to the maximum. Thanks for any guidance you can provide

Comment: @EduardoO. don't have much guidance to provide here. Check the wiki link from my first comment.  If you have trouble with that, make a new question explaining what you want to prove and what you're having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here’s a sketch of one possible argument. Let $u=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)$. (Note that I allow the possibility that $u=\infty$.) There is a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $[a,b]$ such that for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $u-f(x_n)<\frac1{2^n}$ if $u\in\Bbb R$ and $f(x_n)>n$ if $u=\infty$. Extract a monotone subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$. Being a monotone, bounded sequence, $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to some $y$. (Note that you have to use the completeness of $\Bbb R$ in some way, and this is the most elementary that occurs to me.) Moreover, $y\in[a,b]$, and $f$ is continuous, so $f(y)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=u$. (Note that this shows that in fact $u\in\Bbb R$.)

Comment: I really like this proof!  I think you do need to show that $u$ is finite before extracting a suitable sequence, otherwise you can't use convergence. Perhaps that needs its own proof, then.

Comment: Of course, this is just the compactness proof in disguise. It contains a proof that $[a,b]$ is sequentially compact.

Comment: @user14111 good catch, I think you're right about that.  As for my earlier comment: if $f$ is unbounded on $[a,b]$, then by the construction described $f$ would map a convergent sequence to an unbounded sequence, which is a contradiction of continuity, so boundedness doesn't require its own proof after all.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: (Oops! It’s only taken me ten years to notice these comments.) Any sequence in $\Bbb R$ has a monotone subsequence, and $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ lies in $[a,b]$, any subsequence is bounded irrespective of whether $u\in\Bbb R$. That $u\in\Bbb R$ then follows from the fact that it’s $f(y)$ for some $y\in[a,b]$.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, quite a few such proofs exist. You first prove that a continuous function is bounded, and apply the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. Here is such a proof from my lecture notes in a first course in analysis:

> By the earlier result, $\,f$ is bounded. Consider the image of $[a,b]$ under $f$: $$A = f([a,b]) = \left\{f(x) : x \in [a,b]\right\}.$$
> $f$ bounded means that $A$ is bounded as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. We also have that $A \neq \emptyset$. We will prove the existence of $x_2$, and the existence of $x_1$ is proved similarly.

> Since $A$ is bounded and non-empty, there is a supremum: $M=\sup A$. Given any positive integer $n$, $M-1/n$ cannot be an upper bound for $A$. Then there exists some $x_n \in [a,b]$ such that
> $$M-\frac{1}{n} < f(x_n) \leq M. \tag{$*$}$$
> By Bolzano-Weierstrass, $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_{j}} \to x$. Since $a\leq x_{n_{j}}\leq b$, $a\leq x\leq b$. By the continuity of $f$, $\,f(x_{n_{j}}) \to f(x)$. But by $(*)$, $\,f(x_{n_{j}}) \to M$. By the uniqueness of the limit, $\,f(x)=M$. Now set $x_2=x$. $\square$

Answer (score 4):

This theorem ultimately depends on the completeness of real number system and can't be proven without using any result equivalent to the completeness of real number system. If we assume that every continuous function on a closed interval is bounded then we can provide a very simple proof of the current problem being discussed here.

Under this assumption we have the existence of $M = \sup\{f(x)\mid x \in [a, b]\}$. If $f(x)\neq M$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ then the function $g(x) = 1/(M - f(x))$ is continuous in $[a, b]$ and hence bounded in $[a, b]$. On the other hand by definition of $M$ we can find $x \in [a, b]$ such that $M - f(x)$ can be made arbitrarily small. Thus $g(x)$ can be made arbitrarily large. This contradiction shows that we must have $f(x) = M$ for some $x \in [a, b]$.

The result that every continuous function is bounded on a closed interval is itself another property of continuous functions which can't be proved without using completeness of real number system.

I have presented various proofs of these properties of continuous function [here](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/06/continuous-functions-on-closed-interval-boundedness-property.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's a neat twist!  I looked through your linked proofs, which do an impressive job of explaining the topological notion of compactness on $\mathbb R$.  However, I think the better way to approach the proof that "continuous function on a closed interval is bounded" is to use the fact that sequential continuity is equivalent to continuity for metric spaces, and proceed via the B-W theorem (which itself has a neat little proof here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Proof )

Comment: Omnomnomnom, actually the kind of proofs which I have put in my blogs are somewhat easier to understand but limited in their generality (especially they will need lot of development if we want to go for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$). Whereas the proofs based on BW and sequential continuity are the ones which can be applied in a very general context. It also depends on the intended audience and my blog is targeted at people who probably never had undergraduate / graduate education in maths (like myself), but who find maths exciting.

Comment: I think sequential continuity is a lot easier to understand than the Heine Borel principle. In this case, it means we don't need to worry about compactness.

Comment: I agree the proofs based on Heine Borel are on a higher level. Even I had a very difficult time understanding Heine Borel when I first studied from Hardy's Pure Mathematics.

Comment: It seems I didn't give your link a good enough look before making my judgment.  I think your direct use of Dedekind's Theorem is far more intuitive that the notion of sequential compactness.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can avoid compactness entirely. Here's one that uses sequential compactness in the form of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, "every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence". (To justify that theorem to beginners, you could take it as an axiom that every bounded monotonic sequence converges, and show them the proof that every sequence has a monotonic subsequence.) For some reason that escapes me, this proof is often done in two stages, first proving that the function is bounded and then showing that the it attains a maximum.

Given a continuous real-valued function $f$ on $[a,b]$, we will show that
the set $Y = f([a,b])$ has a greatest element.

For each positive integer $n$, define a finite set $Q_n = \{p/q: p,q \text{ integers, } 0 < q \le n, |p| \le n\}$.

Choose $y_n\in Y$ so as to maximize the number of elements in the set $\{r\in Q_n: y_n > r\}$, and choose $x_n\in[a,b]$ with $f(x_n) = y_n$.

The sequence $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence converging to a point $c\in[a,b]$. Since $f$ is continuous, the corresponding subsequence of $\{y_n\}$ converges to $f(c)$. We will show that $f(c)$ is the greatest element of $Y$.

Assume for a contradiction that $f(c)<y\in Y$. Choose a rational
number $r$ so that $f(c)<r<y$. Because of the way $y_n$ was chosen, we
have $y_n > r$ whenever $r\in Q_n$. Since $r\in Q_n$ for all
sufficiently large $n$, we have $y_n > r > f(c)$ for all sufficiently
large $n$. But this is absurd, since $\{y_n\}$ has a subsequence converging
to $f(c)$.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following proof by Takeshi Saito in "How to Learn Mathematics(New Edition)" edited by Kunihiko Kodaira.

Let $X$ be a non-empty compact space.
Let $f(x)$ be a real valued continuous function on $X$.
Assume that $f(x)$ doesn't attain a maximum value on $X$.
Then for any $x \in X$, there exists $t \in X$ such that $f(x) < f(t)$.
Let $U_t := \{x\in X | f(x) < f(t)\}$ for $t \in X$.
$f(x)$ is continuous on $X$, so $U_t$ is an open set of $X$.
$f(x)$ doesn't attain a maximum value on $X$, so $(U_t)_{t\in X}$ is an open cover of $X$.
$X$ is compact, so there exists a finite subcover $U_{t_1}, \cdots, U_{t_n}$.
Let $k \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$ be an integer such that $f(t_k) = \max \{f(t_1), \cdots, f(t_n)\}$.
$t_k \in X$. So there exists an integer $l$ such that $t_k \in U_{t_l}$.
Then, $f(t_k) < f(t_l) \leq f(t_k)$. This is a contradiction.
So, $f(x)$ attains a maximum value on $X$.

We now prove that $[0, 1]$ is compact.
The discrete space $\{0, 1\}$ is finite. So $\{0, 1\}$ is compact. So, $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is compact.
Let $f : \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(\{a_n\}) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2^n}$.
Then, $f$ is continuous, so $f(\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}) = [0,1]$ is compact.

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a \leq b$.
Then, $[a, b] \ne \emptyset$.
And it is easy to show that $[a, b]$ is a compact space:
Let $g : [0, 1] \to [a, b]$ be a function such that $g(x) = (b - a) x + a$.
Since $g$ is continuous, $g([0, 1]) = [a, b]$ is compact.

So, if $f(x)$ is a real valued continuous function on $[a, b]$, then $f(x)$ attains a maximum value on $[a, b]$.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem. Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Then $f([a,b])$ is bounded.

Proof (indirectly) avoiding compactness: Since $f$ is continuous at $a,$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any $x\in [a,a+\delta),$ we have $f(a)-1< f(x)<f(a)+1.$ Hence $f$ is bounded on $[a,a+\delta/2].$ Write 
$$A=\{x\in [a,b]: f \mbox{ is bounded on } [a,x]\}.$$ 
Then $a+\delta/2\in A,$ and $b$ is an upper bound of $A.$ So, let $c=\sup(A).$  Now, $a+\delta/2 \leq c\leq b.$ Continuity of $f$ at $c$ implies that there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that for any $x\in (c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1)\cap [a,b],$ we have $f(c)-1<f(x)<f(c)+1.$ That is, $f$ is bounded on $(c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1)\cap [a,b].$ Let $d\in (c-\delta_1,c).$ Then $f$ is bounded on $[a,d].$ It follows that 
$$f \mbox{ is bounded on } [a,d]\cup\big( (c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1)\cap [a,b]\big).$$
Since $[a,c]\subseteq [a,d]\cup\big( (c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1)\cap [a,b]\big),$ we have $c\in A.$

Further, if $c<b,$ then choose $\delta_2=\min\{\delta_1,(b-c)/2\}.$ Then $[a,c+\delta_2]\subseteq [a,d]\cup\big( (c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1)\cap [a,b]\big).$ It follows that $f$ is bounded on $[a,c+\delta_2].$ So, $c+\delta_2\in A.$ This contradicts the fact that $c=\sup(A).$ Therefore, $c=b.$

Hence $c=b$ and $c\in A.$ That is, $b\in A.$ Therefore, $f$ is bonded on $[a,b].$   QED

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch...

---

The following is a special instance of [Cantor's intersection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem) and it can be proved using an $\text{infimum \ supremum}$ argument:

Proposition: For $a,b \in \mathbb {R}$ with $a \lt b$ let there be given a decreasing nested sequence ${\displaystyle (C_{k})_{k\geq 0}}$ of non-empty  closed subsets of the closed interval $[a,b]$, i.e.

$${\displaystyle C_{0}\supset C_{1}\supset \cdots \supset C_{n}\supset C_{n+1}\supset \cdots ,}$$

Then it follows that

$$ {\displaystyle \bigcap _{k=0}^{\infty }C_{k}\neq \emptyset .}$$

---

Using this it can be easily proven that any continuous real-valued function $s$ on $[a,b]$ must be bounded above (set $C_k$ to the inverse image of $[k,+\infty)$ under $s$ and use a proof by contradiction). Moreover, $s$ must be bounded below (if not, $-s$ would not be bounded above).

---

Once we know that continuous functions are bounded, we can easily show that they attain both a maximum and minimum; see Paramanand Singh's answer. For completeness we use the reasoning here.

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function.

Let

$\; \alpha = \text{infimum(}f\text{<}[a,b]\text{>}\text{)}$

and

$\; \beta = \text{supremum(}f\text{<}[a,b]\text{>}\text{)}$

If $f$ never attains the supremum, then the function

$$ g(x) =  \frac{-1}{f(x)-\beta}$$

defined on $[a,b]$ is not bounded above, a contradiction.

If $f$ never attains the infimum , then the function

$$ h(x) =  \frac{1}{f(x)-\alpha}$$

defined on $[a,b]$ is not bounded above, a contradiction..