# Maximal value of an infinite set.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

Consider a continuous function $f$ over an interval $[a,b]$. Let $S$ be the set of all values that $f(x)$ takes over $I$. Intuitively speaking, I believe this set has a maximal and minimal value. Is this the case? How can I prove it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436676/prove-that-a-continuous-function-on-a-closed-interval-attains-a-maximum

Comment: That existing problem is a bit confusing, since it says "$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and then asserts continuity on $[a,b]$ then asks to prove there is a maximum, which is not true, although there is a maximum on $[a,b]$. @oks