# Proof of the Début theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I was reading the stochastic calculus notes on this website and I read the following in the proof of the [Début theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitting_time) but I could not understand what does it mean. Can someone explain it to me rigorously? Why is this statement true?

http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/stopping-times-and-the-debut-theorem/

Continuous processes always achieve their supremum value on any compact interval,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We deal with continuous stochastic processes quite often (e.g. Brownian motion). The term continuous in here refers to having continuos paths, that is, a stochastic process $X=(X_t)$ is such that for fixed $\omega \in \Omega$ (where $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is the corresponding probability space) a function (a path of $X_t$) 
$$ t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$$
is continuous.

[Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) implies that every continuous function on a compact interval attains its bounds (supremum and infimum).

Therefore, the statement which you were not sure about holds via Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem. For more details you can also see [Prove that a continuous function on a closed interval attains a maximum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436676/prove-that-a-continuous-function-on-a-closed-interval-attains-a-maximum).

Comment: thanks you for clearing it up for me. I guess I need to review some basic real analysis as I have forgotten a few results