# Debut-Theorem and its proof

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

In George Lowther's Blog he is trying to prove the Debut-Theorem for cadlag-processes.

https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/stopping-times-and-the-debut-theorem/

In the continuous case he is using the Bolzano Weierstraß Theorem in order to justify using the maximum process,(someone asked before):

[Proof of the Début theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993464/proof-of-the-d%C3%A9but-theorem)

However I don't understand why the same argumentation cannot be used for Cadlag processes. To be more specific, why should a cadlag function not attain its maximum and minimum in a compact interval? According to the extreme value theorem for semi continuous function, this should be possible, at least for a half of boundedness.

Comment: As far as I can see, a possible flaw would be that he uses the rationals as a countable indexset of the union. This can be done if the function is continuous since if we have two continuous functions which coincide on the rationals then they are equal on the reals. I think this is wrong in general if the functions are only semicontinuous.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek Thanks, that is the mainpoint of my question. However, I still can choose a dense set from left hand side and approximate any point on real. Because the left limit exists, I will be able to show the value will coincide. Could you give a counter example to illustrate why this is not true in general?