# Does a continuous function from $[a,b]$ to $[c,d)$ exist?

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and its image is a semi-open interval $[c,d)$ (both of them are in $\Bbb R$)

If this function exist, give an example, or prove it doesn't exist.

At first I tried to found an example but everything lead me to a contradiction and I've tried to prove it doesn't exist but I'm going round in circles.
Any advice will be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: [A continuous real function obtains its extreme values on a closed interval.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436676/prove-that-a-continuous-function-on-a-closed-interval-attains-a-maximum) Every value between those extremes is also attained by the function (through Intermediate Value Theorem). Thus, the image of a closed interval is a closed interval under a continuous function.

Comment: Alternatively, from topology: the continuous image of a compact space is a compact space. $[c,d)$ is not compact, $[a,b]$ is compact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say such function does exist. Since it's image is $[c,d)$, we know $f$ reaches values arbitrarily close to $d$ on the interval $[a,b]$ but never actually reaches $d$. So, let's make a sequence of values of $f$ that get closer and closer to $d$.

Let's define $x_n$ as a sequence of numbers in $[a,b]$, such that
$$|f(x_n)-d| < \tfrac1{2^n}$$

Does this seem familiar? If you know about limits, this is pretty much the definition of a limit. So, we see

$$\lim f(x_n) = d = f(\lim x_n)$$
But, since all $x_n\in[a,b]$, we know $\lim x_n\in[a,b]$. So, let $X = \lim x_n$, and we see $f(X) = d$. This is a contradiction, because we assumed $f$ didn't reach $d$ on $[a,b]$.

We conclude, such function does not exist.

Comment: I think this is sound, but _how_ do we know that $\lim x_n\in[a,b]$? None of us would be surprised to find a limit doing weird stuff, so this requires justification.

Comment: Often enough, closed intervals are defined as containing the limits of every sequence they contain. So, if that's the case, there's really not much proving to be done and follows from definition.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem:
The image of a closed, bounded interval under a continuous map is closed and bounded.

Proof:

The image of an interval $I = [a, b]$ is bounded and is a subset of$ [m, M] $(say) where m, M are the lub and glb of the image. Since the function attains its bounds, $m, M ∈ f (I) $and so the image is $[m, M].$

See more here:[Image of a continuous function](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/analysis/Lectures/L22.html)

Comment: Presumably no, because ∞ isn't an element of the reals, as specified.

Comment: In that case the domain will be a open interval :/

Comment: You are right, my bad. I forgot that there is a theorem. I will edit my answer

Comment: Well, that basically solves all my problems