# $[0,1]$ is compact. Why is $f:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\ni (a_n) \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2^n}\in\mathbb{R}$ continuous? Takeshi Saito's proof.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, binary

I am reading "How to Learn Mathematics (New Edition)" (in Japanese) edited by Kunihiko Kodaira.

Few years ago, I posted my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3097157/384082) for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/436676/384082).

My answer was copy and paste from the above book and I don't perfectly understand my answer.

> $[0, 1]$ is compact.
>
> Takeshi Saito's proof:
> The discrete space $\{0, 1\}$ is finite. So $\{0, 1\}$ is compact. So, $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is compact.
> Let $f : \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f((a_n)) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2^n}$.
> Then, $f$ is continuous, so $f(\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}) = [0,1]$ is compact.

I filled gaps of the above proof as follows:
Since $\{0,1\}$ is finite and finite topological spaces are compact, $\{0,1\}$ is compact.
By Tychonoff's Theorem, $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is compact.
***And I don't undrstand why $f : \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f((a_n)) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2^n}$ is continuous.***
Since continuous image of a compact set is compact by a famous proposition, $f(\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}})$ is compact.
And $f(\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}})=[0,1]$.
So, $[0,1]$ is compact.

Please prove that $f : \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f((a_n)) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2^n}$ is continuous.

Comment: What did you try to prove it yourself? You can start by identifying a basis of a point in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$. I have to say, however, that Saito's proof is kind of ridiculous, since it's much more complex than the standard proof, just the complexity is hidden. For instance, he takes Tychonoff's theorem for granted...

Comment: **Hint.** Since you are mentioning Tychonov's theorem you must be familiar with product topologies. Can you begin to prove first that, for every $n\in\Bbb{N}$, the map $\pi_n\colon 2^{\Bbb{N}}\to \{0,1\}$ defined by $\pi_n\big((a_i)_i\big)=a_n$ is continuous.

Comment: @jpboucheron $\pi_n^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$. $\pi_n^{-1}(\{0,1\})=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. $\pi_n^{-1}(\{0\})=\{0,1\}\times\dots\times\{0\}\times\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\times\cdots$. $\pi_n^{-1}(\{1\})=\{0,1\}\times\dots\times\{1\}\times\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\times\cdots$. These sets are open in $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. So, $\pi_n$ is continuous.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @tchappyha That's OK (also there's a more “synthetic” definition for the product topology: it is the smallest one that makes all projections $\pi_n$ continuous). Now consider the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\Bbb{N}} \frac{\pi_n}{2^n}\cdot$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\displaystyle f=\sum_n\frac{\pi_n}{2^n}$, where $\pi_n\colon 2^{\Bbb N}\kern-5mu\longrightarrow \{0,1\}\kern5mu$ is the $n^{\scriptscriptstyle \rm th}$ projection.

These projections are continuous (by definition of the product topology), hence $f$ —being a *normally convergent series of continuous functions*— is continuous.

Comment: jp boucheron, Thank you very much for your comments and answer.

Comment: @tchappyha You're very welcome. I will add an observation about this context: the compactness of $X=2^{\Bbb{N}}$ can be proved without making use of Tychonoff, because in this case $X$ can be equipped with a distance such that —as a metric space— $(X,d)$ has the *same open sets* as the product topology. For example $d\big( (a_n)_n,(b_n)_n \big)=\sum_n \frac{|a_n-b_n|}{2^n}\cdot$ Another possibility that gives the same topology is $\max_n \sum_n \frac{|a_n-b_n|}{n+1}\cdot$ And then it's possible to show directly the sequential compactness.